# how to get the file stored as a blob using filename in app engine using java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, blob

i have already uploaded the file..now i need to search and download the file in blob using the file name...i could implement the following code for file name retrieve....

BlobInfo blobInfo = blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey)

String blobFilename = blobInfo.getFilename();

now to get download the file using this?

Answer (score 2):

Just follow this guide, from the App Engine documentation: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Serving_a_Blob

Comment: ya i have given tat in servlet...but how to receive the actual file in  my HTML file?

Comment: A servlet is mapped to an URL. For example, in `myapp.appspot.com/downloads?file=myfile`, the servlet points to `/downloads`. In your HTML, just serve that URL to the user. The browser will prompt the user to save the file.

Comment: This is a good tutorial for you: http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html

Comment: how to download without using tomcat?

Comment: App Engine uses a Jetty. You need a [servlet container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) to run... servlets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Content Type

```
response.setContentLength(new Long(blobInfo.getSize()).intValue()); 
response.setHeader("content-type", blobInfo.getContentType()); 
response.setHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
blobInfo.getFilename()); 
blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);
```

Comment: how to add download link for in my form in html?

Comment: call your servlet from html by an href Link--
    <a href="SERVLET_PATH"> DOWNLOAD FILE </a>

Comment: does the servlet path refer to "projectname/servletname" ??